# Mysql and PHP inbox update

Tags: php, mysql, sql-insert, sql-delete, inbox

I have created an inbox system. Signed in user can message other signed in users. The usermessage Table from database has two fields 1. userid and 2. messageid. The following is an excerpt from this table.

```
userid | messageid
12     | 1
13     | 1
14     | 2
15     | 2
12     | 3
15     | 3
12     | 4
14     | 4
```

In above situation when user '12' send message to user '13'. I want the messageid '1' to move to bottom of the table so that when the user '12' or '13' is checking his mailbox, the messageid '1' needs to appear on the top of inbox as a recent conversation. So far I have been able to achieve this by deleting the messageid '1' and inserting as a new query for each userid. This is my code:

```
DELETE FROM usermessage WHERE userid = '12' and messageid = '1';
INSERT INTO usermessage SET userid = '12', messageid = '1';
DELETE FROM usermessage WHERE userid = '13' and messageid = '1';
INSERT INTO usermessage SET userid = '13', messageid = '1';
```

Is it possible get this done with one query. So far, I was not able to find any definite answer in stackflow related to my problem.

Comment: OMG. did you ever hear about normalizing data and good relative-db design?

Comment: This would be much better achieved with a timestamp field on the usermessage table (using something like ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) and a more sensible ORDER BY on the select for displaying the inbox.

Comment: shouldn't 12 sending to 13 just create a new row, you shouldn't be recycling message id.

Comment: @heximal how are your critical commments going to help anything? please be more constructive. Links, examples anything.

Comment: @heximal While I totally agree, I expect normal forms to be wayyyy down the priority list for this one :-)

Comment: @hexiaml: thank you for your response. I am a starter and I am learning more about this.

Comment: sorry, just i haven't been seen something like this for long long time. I tried to formulate my answer, but couldn't decide what to advice the author as starting point.

Comment: @cbuckley timestamp does look much better. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Querying rows without SORT statement gives no guaranties that they will be sorted in the created time order. Its is just a chance that MySQL gives you such a sorting behavior since now.

So it is necessary that you found or create an objective sorting rule. It can be the timestamp of the message, or a new timestamp column in you [usermessage] table.

It is also noticeable that deleting and re-creating rows will affect the MySQL process cost because MySQL will need to update the indexes on [usermessage] table each time you delete and insert.

Comment: Thank you. Timestamp is a definite answer.